# Django, Select model field type based on database backend

Tags: django, django-models

I want to select model field type based on database backend. So, for instance, it database backend is SQLite, then field type will be TextField. But if backend is PostgreSQL, then field type will be JSONField. Field name will be the same in all cases. Of course I understand that code processing the field may need branching too, but it is not the problem. Problem is to add field early enough, so that migrations, etc. will work.